# iPhone Testing Device Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have iAds in my application, I followed a tutorial to make sure they run on iOS 3.0 and above, but how can I test this to make sure they do, and don't crash?

I'm using Xcode 4.1, and it only has SDK 4.3!  Is there a way I can run this on a older version of iOS SDK such as iOS 3?

I'm running OSX Lion, so I can't download those older versions of Xcode.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the base SDK version in the build settings, as Tomen says, but I'll add that it's not possible to know whether/not it will crash without testing.

Symbols that you can't use on that iOS version won't resolve at runtime (with weak linking, they will be NULL/nil/Nil) or throw errors at compile time (without weak linking, which I believe is the default), so you are *reasonably* safe, as the headers do include availability and deprecation information.

This is a reasonably good assurance that the application will, at the very least, launch (in a technical sense,) but there is no substitute for on-device testing. Unfortunately, without an old device, you cannot install iOS 3, as Apple seems bent on cutting backwards compatibility and making certain that developers only target modern versions of iOS.

Comment: Thanks, I found out you can not install SDK 3 on Lion

Answer (score 0):

set the base SDK version in the build settings

Comment: That doesn't show if it will crash or not!  I used an older build of my project where the iAd forces a crash on iOS 3.2, and it will not no when I run in simulator 4.3, but this will on devices running iOS 3